# Is it possible to disable the theader of an empty table in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is my sample table

[image: Sample Table]

My table has sorters so my header is clickable. What I want to do is if the table is empty, I want my headers to be disabled or not clickable. Is this possible with css? Is there any other approach I can do to do this? Below is the code I used for the columns. My data is from a dataSource.

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'LAST NAME',
        dataIndex: 'lastName',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName),
        width: '15%'
    },
    {
        title: 'FIRST NAME',
        dataIndex: 'givenName',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.givenName.localeCompare(b.givenName),
        width: '15%'
    },
    {
        title: 'MIDDLE NAME',
        dataIndex: 'middleName',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.middleName.localeCompare(b.middleName),
        width: '15%'
    }, 
    {
        title: 'DATE OF BIRTH',
        dataIndex: 'dateOfBirth',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.dateOfBirth.localeCompare(b.dateOfBirth),
        width: '14%'
    },
    {
        title: 'GENDER',
        dataIndex: 'sex',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.sex.localeCompare(b.sex),
        width: '12%'
    },
    {
        title: 'ADDRESS',
        dataIndex: 'address',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.localeCompare(b.address),
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is to extract the sort functions I'd like to be disabled to pass them my data, and then return `false` if data is empty. Something like this :

```
    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'LAST NAME',
            dataIndex: 'lastName',
            sorter: getSorter(myDataSource),
            width: '15%'
        }
    ];

    getSorter = (myDataSource) => myDataSource.length > 0 ? (a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName) : false;
```

So :

1. Pass the datasource down to a function that will be responsible for creating the sorting function
2. Check if that datasource is empty:

   2a. If it's empty, return false (which will remove the sorting options)

   2b. If not, return the sorting function

[Here](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) is the documentation for the `column` props that states that you can either pass a function or a boolean to the `sorter` property.

Comment: this worked. added a few bits to it and it worked perfectly. thanks!

Comment: @Alexandria.Omega.Reid glad I could help! May I ask you to accept the answer if it worked as you wanted? :)

Comment: I would like to not to show the headers, when there is no data. Does antd provide this configuration?